# Problems with Natbib: strange URL format and urldate not shown

Tags: natbib, urls

I have a strange problem with natbib. This code

```
@misc{CornellUniversity.,
  author = {{Cornell University}},
  title = {Benedict R. O'G. Anderson},
  url = {\url{http://www.cornell.edu/search/index.cfm?tab=people&netid=bra2&q=benedict%20anderson}},
  urldate = {2012-03-18}
}
```

creates the following output:

```
Cornell University. Benedict R. O’G. Anderson. URL http://www.cornell.edu/search/index.cfm?tab=people&netid=bra2&q=benedict%20anderson.
```

where:

1) The text "URL" is placed in front of the actual url

2) the url is not formated as a hyperlink (the url package is included)

3) the "urldate" property doesn't show up at all

How do I best solve those issues?

Comment: The formatting of bibliographic entries -- including the insertion of the string "URL" ahead of the actual url - is not controlled by the `natbib` package, but by the bibliography style you employ. The bibliography style also determines what may (or may not) be done with fields such as `urldate`. In short: Which bibliography style do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `url` field should just contain the web address, no tex formatting around it.  So in this case you should remove the command `\url`.  Also, standard `natbib` styles do not provide a `urldate` field.  Instead you can put the information in the `note` field:

[image: Sample output]

from

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

Citing \cite{CornellUniversity.}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

with `refs.bib` containing

```
@misc{CornellUniversity.,
  author = {{Cornell University}},
  title = {{Benedict R. O'G. Anderson}},
  url = {http://www.cornell.edu/search/index.cfm?tab=people&netid=bra2&q=benedict%20anderson},
  note = {Last visited 2012-03-18}
}
```

As @Mico points out, extra braces around the title field prevent its case being changed by `bibtex`.

Comment: You may want to encase the title in double braces, so that uppercase letters won't be converted to lowercase...

Comment: @Mico Of course.  Updated now.

Comment: In order to solve the first issue, one would have to hack `plainnat.bst`.

Answer (score 12):

If you have in your code `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` then the "URL" text comes from the style.

In the `plainnat.bst` file you can find the following code:

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
   { "" }
   { new.block "URL \url{" url * "}" * }
   if$
}
```

The part `"URL \url{" url * "}" *` is responsible for your problem. You can delete URL at the start of it or change it in any way you like.

For the urldate (it is a little more complicated):

In the same `plainnat.bst` file for example under the code above add the following lines:

```
FUNCTION {format.urldate}
{ urldate empty$
   { "" }
   {new.block  "[Accessed on: " urldate * "]" * }
  if$
}
```

Save it and do a search in the same file for "url". In one place you will find:

```
ENTRY
{ address
author
........%some more functions
type
url
volume
year
}
```

Add `urldate` under `url`. Save it. Then do a search for `format.url output` and add under every single one `format.urldate output`.

For example by `misc`:

```
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  title howpublished new.block.checkb
  format.title output
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished output
  format.date output
  format.issn output
  format.url output
  note output
  format.urldate output     %places the "urldate" after the "note"
  new.block
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}
```

So, the order of the different outputs (e.g. format.urldate output) in the different functions (e.g. misc) denotes also the order of their insertion in the references.

That is all :)

Comment: After 2 hours of googling and 1 hour of tweaking different solutions I've found this one the best. +1

Comment: @Mico That is actually what I ment under:                                                _"Then do a search for format.url output and add under every single one format.urldate output."_

Comment: @Mico - Sure :) I have also added an example. I hope that it helps.

Comment: It's great now! :-) (I've already upvoted.)

Comment: I don't think this is a good way of doing it if your software comes from a repository.