# Modifying natbib to include Access Date and < > around <urls>

Tags: cross-referencing, harvard-style

I am trying to respect Harvard referencing rules of my university impose. I am using natbib library and I am trying to include Access Date at the end of website references and surround urls with < and > (so ). I managed to include access date manually by adding "note" in bibtex. But every time I try to include < or \< in url field errors start to appear.

```
@misc{Berners-Lee2006,
author = {Berners-Lee, Tim},
title = {{Linked Data}},
url = {http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/LinkedData.html},
note = {[Accessed on 04 January 2017]},
year = {2006}
}
```

Is there an automatic (if not, manual) way to solve this issue?

**UPDATE:**

Please find the answer here: [tex.stackexchange.com/a/306341/99908](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306341/99908) .

Comment: Found the answer here: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306341/99908]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it appears to have been solved via the link shown in the comment below the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make my bibliography according to harvard-style (author-year, alphabetical by sourcetype...) in Lyx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146159/how-do-i-make-my-bibliography-according-to-harvard-style-author-year-alphabeti)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with Natbib: strange URL format and urldate not shown](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103133/problems-with-natbib-strange-url-format-and-urldate-not-shown)